# How nginx is listening when Listen is black out

Tags: nginx

Focal Fossa

I commented the listen in server directive:
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {

#       listen 0.0.0.0:80 default_server;
#       listen [::]:80 default_server;
```

and I am not sure if I should get this:

```
netstat -plant |g ng
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      8417/nginx: master  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:41618         ESTABLISHED 8418/nginx: worker  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:80            127.0.0.1:41616         ESTABLISHED 8418/nginx: worker
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: I do not think that your question will answer the OP.

Comment: By removing the `listen` directives, Nginx is using the [default value](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen).

Comment: true, but is not that exactly what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen):

> If the directive is not present then either *:80 is used if nginx runs with the superuser privileges, or *:8000 otherwise.

Comment: is this default *:80 somewhere else in the nginx code? I mean other than /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.